# Mocking the date in Protractor

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

I am writing a suite of end to end tests for my angular (4) application, using protractor. My backend is configured to connect to an exact replica of the production database, but filled with dummy data.

A big part of my front end, is correctly displaying historic data. Currently, there is a certain period which has the data I want to display. However, obviously in a weeks time, my "Weekly" view will display all data as 0.

Is it possible to trick protractor into thinking the date is within the period I seeded the dummy data, so the displayed data is predictable?

## Update:

I now have this code:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

describe('Login & Home Page', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        let date = moment('08-03-2017');
        moment = () => { return date };
    })
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Date` constructor in your code you can override the same.

```
var d = new Date(2017, 5, 14);
Date = function(){return d;};
```

Depends on how you are getting date in your code, however it is override the same to return desired dates.

If you are using moment then override the exact same function(s) you are using.

```
let date = moment(2017, 6, 14);
moment = () => {return date};
```

---

```
 describe('Login & Home Page', () => {
    let realMoment = moment;
    let moment = function(){
        this.prototype = realMoment.prototype;
        return realMoment('08-03-2017', 'MM-DD-YYYY'); 
    };
    beforeEach(() => {
    });
    it('expect moment(\'asd\') to return 08-03-2017', () => {
       expect(moment('asd').format('MM-DD-YYYY')).toBe('08-03-2017'))
    });
```

---

Well, I guess `jasmine.clock.mockDate()` is the actual way to go

```
var today = moment('2015-10-19').toDate();
jasmine.clock().mockDate(today);
expect(moment().valueOf()).toEqual(today.valueOf());
```

Comment: I am using the `moment()` constructor. What I don't understand is where I am supposed to override this function? In the `BeforeEach()` of my protractor tests?

Comment: You can do it in `beforeEach()` if you want it applied to all items in the suite, or you can do it in `it` if you want this change limited to a single test. Both should work. I hope you are using a global `moment`. Also make sure you provide aliases to other `moment` function you have used in your code, or it will fail.

Comment: OK, If you see my updated question, you can see what  have, however, I get the compiler error `[ts] Cannot assign to 'moment' because it is not a variable`, how do I do this in TypeScript

Comment: try `const moment=` or `let moment=`

Comment: If I do that, then I get `Block-scoped variable 'moment' used before its declaration.` on the `let date = moment(2017, 6, 14);` line?

Comment: Can you make sure `moment` is available to the spec already? or else you need to import moment to your spec file first. Also check the updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146881/discussion-between-george-edwards-and-sabithpocker).