# jasmine.clock().mockDate(...) not working with Angular E2E tests

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

According to my research (e.g. [Mocking the date in Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44545638/mocking-the-date-in-protractor)) we should be able to fake the current date by using the following lines in an Angular E2E test with Protractor:

```
it('should display the fake date put in place via jasmine.clock().mockDate()', async () => {
  jasmine.clock().install();
  jasmine.clock().mockDate(new Date(2040, 0, 1));

  await page.navigateTo();
  const result = await page.getCurrentDateDisplayed();
  expect(result).toEqual('2040-01-01');

  jasmine.clock().uninstall();
});
```

However, this does not seem to work for me and I don't understand why. The test output indicates that faking the date did not work at all, it's using the current date:

```
Expected '2019-02-02' to equal '2040-01-01'.
```

Here's also the app.component.ts and the corresponding html template:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
      Current date is <span class="e2e-curr-date">{{currentDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span>.
    </h1>
  </div>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  currentDate = new Date();
}
```

Here's also the full source: https://github.com/baumgarb/ng-e2e-test-w-jasmine-clock

Comment: Oh no! I've just noticed this, too! BOO...